# Remove unused opencv dlls in a project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, dll

I have a project which depends on OpenCV, but not all of its .dlls. Actually as I know I just used some functions in highgui/core etc, and when I compile my project in VS2010, I just linked highgui/core/contrib/imagproc .libs. However, when I run the exe, it says other dlls such as "opencv_video242.dll is missing from your computer", which means I have to copy all the opencv dlls if I want the program to run.

So how to remove the unused opencv dlls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check wich DLL's needed for your program using [Dependency Walker tool](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

It will give you a dependency tree of dll's.

Answer (score 0):

I have known why. Contrib depends on lots of dlls such as opencv_video/features/ etc..

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the libs which are used in the project and their corresponding DLLs.
If you have included unused libs in your project Dependency walker will still show the dependencies of the DLLs not used.